# Append dataframe columns in a loop to yield a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote code to extract data from a csv and put them into a dataframe and sort them after. The code looks as such:

```
def highest_value_sorter(value):
    sorted_df = df_result[value].astype('float64').sort_values(ascending=False)
    sorted_df = sorted_df.head(10).to_frame().reset_index()
    return sorted_df

sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[values])

for value in values:
    sorted_tmp_df = highest_value_sorter(value)
    sorted_tmp_df = sorted_tmp_df.drop(columns=['index'])
```

sorted_tmp_df in my code yields the following result in a loop:

```
       apples
    0             922640.524589
    1             862396.590682
    2             848624.249550

   oranges
0               2.394991e+11
1               1.875155e+11
2               6.409508e+10

   bananas
0               1.852440e+08
1               6.143871e+07
2               5.757801e+07
```

my goal is to get all of these into one dataframe as such:

```
       apples                          oranges
    0             922640.524589        862396.590682
    1             862396.590682        5.757801e+07
    2             5.757801e+07         922640.524589
```

So far I've tried .join and .append as such: sorted_df = sorted_df.append(sorted_tmp_df)/sorted_df = sorted_df.join(sorted_tmp_df) and neither seem to work. Any tips would help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat list of dataframes on columns with `axis` set to 1.

```py
dfs = []

for value in values:
    sorted_tmp_df = highest_value_sorter(value)
    sorted_tmp_df = sorted_tmp_df.drop(columns=['index'])
    dfs.append(sorted_tmp_df)

df_ = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```